# why Angular JS is named Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Please don't insult if I ask that in the bad website or bad section with the bad tags but I would like to know .

why the javascript framework angularJS has been named angularJS?

Comment: Seems like you didn't look very hard. It's literally the first question on their FAQ. https://www.google.co.jp/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=why+is+angularjs+called+angular&gws_rd=cr&ei=hT7IV7WOJoOk0ATx4ZKAAw

Comment: *JS* suffix is an attempt to follow the fashion and tag the library by its language (was made optional later and cannot be applied to Angular 2, which is multilingual).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just googled: "why is angular js called angular".

Result: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

> Because HTML has Angular brackets and "ng" sounds like "Angular".

Answer (score 5):

Because Angular JS can be written inside the angle brackets of HTML that is why it is known as Angular JS .

The use of 'ng' commonly in all its directives is to make the browser understand that this html page is making use of aNGular JS(Note the capital Letters)

Answer (score 1):

Because html has angular brackets and ng rhymes with angular, ng = next generation, as in angular is the next generation of html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).